# Input without stopping program

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, python-multithreading, python-asyncio

I am trying to make a countdown timer that prints the time remaining, and when you input something, it prints what you inputted. My problem is I don't want to wait for the input, just keep running the timer. My incorrect code:

```
timer = 100
while True:
    print(timer)
    timer -= 1

    if input('> '):
        print('the output of input')
```

You could say I want to have the timer printing the time in the background.

Comment: look for `getch()` or similar function - it is not in standard library.

Comment: If you're using a unix-like OS, you can `select([sys.stdin])`, or use `curses.getch`, if on Windows, then it is more complicated.

Comment: so if `select([sys.stdin]) != ''` then do x

Comment: You can also use a [threading.Timer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#timer-objects) object and keep the blocking `input` call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a function that will timeout if no input is given:

```
import select
import sys

def timeout_input(timeout, prompt="", timeout_value=None):
    sys.stdout.write(prompt)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    ready, _, _ = select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], timeout)
    if ready:
        return sys.stdin.readline().rstrip('\n')
    else:
        sys.stdout.write('\n')
        sys.stdout.flush()
        return timeout_value
```

You can easily modify it so it shows the remaining time by changing the timeout value on `select.select` to `1`, and looping `timeout` times.

Answer (score 1):

Standard input and standard output (accessed via `input()` and `print()`) are not a good choice for writing interactive asynchronous user interface (UI).  Python support a few UIs via it's standard library.  For example, [curses](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html) is a text based user interface available on many POSIX systems.  Here is an exmaple code for showing a countdown timer while accepting a number from the user:

```
import time
import curses


def get_number(seconds):
    def _get_number(stdscr):
        stdscr.clear()
        timeout = time.time() + seconds
        s = ""
        while time.time() <= timeout:
            time_left = int(timeout - time.time())
            stdscr.addstr(0, 0, 'Countdown: {} {}'.format(time_left,
                                                          "*" * time_left + " " * seconds))
            stdscr.addstr(2, 0, ' ' * 50)
            stdscr.addstr(2, 0, 'Your Input: {}'.format(s))
            stdscr.refresh()
            stdscr.timeout(100)
            code = stdscr.getch()
            stdscr.addstr(10, 0, 'Code: {}'.format(code))  # for debug only
            stdscr.refresh()
            if ord("0") <= code <= ord("9"):
                s += chr(code)
                continue

            if code == 10 and s:  # newline
                return int(s)

            if code == 127:  # backspace
                s = s[:-1]

    return curses.wrapper(_get_number)

print(get_number(10))
```

Comment: The problem with this is I need to accept strings of a 2 digit length.

Comment: So instead of `if code == 10 and s` write `if len(s) == 2`

Comment: doesn't `getch` get 1 character?

Comment: Yes, but see the loop with `s += ...` above. Just try the code.